# nullpointerexception for array of objects

Tags: arrays, object, nullpointerexception

I have the following test class

```
public class Driver
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
        {
             BankAccount[] b1 = {new BankAccount(200), new BankAccount(300), new BankAccount(250), new BankAccount(300), new BankAccount(200)};
              BankAccountGroup bag = new BankAccountGroup(b1);                      

        }
```

And BankAccountGroup:

```
public class BankAccountGroup 
{ 
private BankAccount bank[];
public BankAccountGroup(BankAccount[]b)
{
for(int i =0; i<5;i++)
{
bank[i] = b[i];
}
}
```

these are just snippets of the whole code. Im getting a nullpointerexception for these two lines:
- bank[i] = b[i];
- BankAccountGroup bag = new BankAccountGroup(b1);
Please help

Answer (score 1):

When you declare bank[] in the BankAccountGroup class it looks like you forgot to give it a length. Because of this, when you call bank[i] in your for loop, anything after i=0 is probably going to give you an error.

something like

```
private BankAccount[] bank = new BankAccount[5];
```

Comment: Can you mark this as the answer? IMTRYINGTOGETSOMEPOINTS.

Answer (score 1):

Either initialize your array first(Bad).

Or assign it from the value you pass the constructor.

```
private BankAccount[] bank;
public BankAccountGroup(BankAccount []){
       bank = b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not initializing the bank array. You also shouldn't assume that the argument will have a length of 5 elements. I would rewrite the class to something like this:

```
 public class BankAccountGroup 
{ 
    private BankAccount bank[];

    public BankAccountGroup(BankAccount[]b)
    {
        if (b != null)
        {
            bank = new BankAccount[b.length];

            for(int i=0; i<b.length;i++)
            {
                bank[i] = b[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```